# For all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k > 0$ : $(a+b)^{2} \geq \dfrac{a^{2}}{1+k} - \dfrac{b^{2}}{k} $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

For all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k > 0$ we have
$$
(a+b)^{2} \geq \dfrac{a^{2}}{1+k} - \dfrac{b^{2}}{k} 
$$
Why?

I have shown that the above inequality is valid if and only if $b = \dfrac{k}{1+k}a$ and and which does not hold for $k < 0$, because
$$
\lim_{k \to 0^{-}} \dfrac{a^{2}}{1+k} - \dfrac{b^{2}}{k} = +\infty
$$

Comment: $a = 1$,$b = 0$ and $k = 1$ certainly makes the inequality true so you cannot have proven that it holds "... if and only if $b =\frac{k}{1+k}a$". Also why the statement about $k<0$? The question says for $k > 0$ no?

Comment: While there is surely a clever algebraic solution, one could also simply differentiate with respect to into find the maximum value of the left hand side.

Comment: When in doubt, multiply out! That is, expand the left side, multiply both sides by $k(k+1)$ to clear fractions, combine like terms, and see what you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
k(1+k)\left((a+b)^{2} - \dfrac{a^{2}}{1+k} + \dfrac{b^{2}}{k}\right)=\left(ka+(1+k)b\right)^2\ge0
$$

Comment: Not leaving much for OP to do.

Answer (score 4):

That reminds me of Titu's lemma
$$\frac{\left ( a+ b \right )^{2}}{1}+ \frac{\left ( -b \right )^{2}}{k}\geq\frac{\left ( a+ b- b \right )^{2}}{k+ 1}$$